# Transform a varchar field with #-delimiters into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, string-splitting

I am working with a database where some data (integer values representing selected options of a dropdown menue) is saved as a string (varchar) inside only one table column. In `products_table` (let's say), there is a `product_id` column mapped to a `selected-options` column. In the latter, data is saved as `#3#9#15#` where 3, 9 and 15 are IDs of dropdown menue options that have been selected by a user. There is another table (let's say `option_table`) where each of these options with IDs 1 to 15 are given more attributes (like a `label` and a `weight`).

For statistical reasons, I want to create a MySQL view with the columns `selected option` and `number of products` (the number of products where this option has been selected). To get there, I need the single values from `#3#9#15#`, that is, explode the string somewhere on the way.

Now I read that this form of saving data is not encouraged, which is why there is no built-in explode/split function for strings in MySQL. But I cannot change the data format, which has been determined inside a huge software. I didn't make this design choice, but I have to somehow work with it.

Working with the built-in function `substring_index()` is no choice because the number of selected options saved in this field varies, from 0 to 15. Also, the maximum number is not fix, as new options may be created from time to time.

I tried writing an own procedure that will take one number from `#3#9#15#` (for example, by repeatedly trimming the # delimiters) and create a new row with it. The procedure should access the value with a `SELECT` statement, create a new view with `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, and then insert a new row with only the first option (3) option with `` INSERT INTO `viewname`(`product_id`,`option`) VALUES(@productID, SUBSTR(@options,2,1)); `` where `@options == #3#9#15#` for example. I tried writing the procedure for only the first option at the beginning, but it already failed at this stage.

Other ideas I had included trying to convert the string `@options` into a SET datatype, so I can use `find_in_set()` function. I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910193/split-string-to-substrings-on-a-character-and-turn-into-multiple-lines-sql) and [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) but found them very hard to understand.

Having only basic knowledge of MySQL, is there some way for me to create this view? I would be very thankful for any hint in which direction I should go on researching.

***Edit***: I have server version 10.3.28 - MariaDB Server. Do you need more information on this?

***Edit2***: Due to an (ongoing) bug in phpMyAdmin, I could not use SQL `WITH` statement ([see here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/331)).

***Edit3***: It turned out that the delimiter used by the software was not actually a `#` sign, but was only displayed by phpMyAdmin as such. It was instead the ASCII control character `0001` or `"^A"`.

Comment: *data is saved as #3#9#15# where 3, 9 and 15 are IDs* Storing multiple data in one column in CSV from (your format is modified CSV) is bad practice. Normalizing strongly recommended.

Comment: *is there some way for me to create this view?* Of course.  Specify **precise** version of your server.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongly based on @matigo's answer, I figured out the following SQL call to be included in phpMyAdmin's `CREATE VIEW viewname AS ...`. It takes a value from one table column (as well as an ID that is given to this value in another table), splits the value at every instance of a specified delimiter (here: `CHAR(1)`) and outputs these split values together with the beforementioned ID.

Information about the setting: We have two tables where we take information from, one called `split_table_name` here (it contains the column `split_column_name` with values that should be split at the delimiter) and another table called `id_table_name` (contains a unique ID for the products; this ID is included in `split_table_name` as a foreign key column called `id_table_id`).

Please note that the delimiter used by the software was not actually a `#` sign (as I assumed in my question), but was only displayed by phpMyAdmin as such. It was in fact the ASCII control character 0001. So I needed to convert it to a char with `CHAR(1)` so I would be able to use it in `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

```
  SELECT CAST(
      COALESCE(
NULLIF(
SUBSTRING_INDEX ((SUBSTRING_INDEX (split_column_alias, CHAR(1), num.id)), CHAR(1), -1), ''),
          '0')  AS SIGNED)
     as one_split, content_alias.id_column_alias as `id_column_alias` FROM
(SELECT `split_table_alias`.`split_column_name` AS `split_column_alias`, `id_table_alias`.`id` AS `id_column_alias`
FROM `database_name`.`split_table_name` `split_table_alias`
JOIN `database_name`.`id_table_name` `id_table_alias`
ON `id_table_alias`.`id` = `split_table_alias`.`id_table_id`
        ) content_alias
INNER JOIN
(SELECT (h*10+t+1) as id FROM (
      SELECT 0 h  UNION
      SELECT 1    UNION
      SELECT 2    UNION
      SELECT 3    UNION
      SELECT 4    UNION
      SELECT 5    UNION
      SELECT 6    UNION
      SELECT 7    UNION
      SELECT 8    UNION
      SELECT 9) a,
    (
      SELECT 0 t  UNION
      SELECT 1    UNION
      SELECT 2    UNION
      SELECT 3    UNION
      SELECT 4    UNION
      SELECT 5    UNION
      SELECT 6    UNION
      SELECT 7    UNION
      SELECT 8    UNION
      SELECT 9) b ) num
WHERE num.id > 0
) zz
WHERE zz.one_split > 0
ORDER BY zz.one_split;
```

Comment: I added a more detailed version of my solution here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/how-to-split-civicrm-multiple-database-values-with-sql

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT zz.`idx`
  FROM (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('#3#9#15#', '#', num.`id`), '#', -1) AS SIGNED) as `idx`
          FROM (SELECT (h*10+t+1) as `id`
                  FROM (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
                       (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b) num
                 WHERE num.`id` > 0) zz
 WHERE zz.`idx` > 0
 ORDER BY zz.`idx`;
```

You can pass up to 100 `#`-separated IDs into the string and get what you need split out as an `UNSIGNED` integer.